# Problemas partida servidor rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hola estoy intentando iniciar un servidor en rails mediante rails s, pero cada vez que lo intento me aparece el error

> ansi: 'gem install win32console' to use color on Windows

instalo la gema pero este error no se soluciona, intente ingresar a la carpeta que contiene ansi dentro de las gemas e hice unas modificaciones a esta sin ningún resultado positivo. A alguno le ha pasado este problema?

> version ruby: ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x64-mingw32]
>
> version rails: Rails 5.1.6

Comment: Creo que esto puede ayudarte: https://github.com/L2G/windowtint Si funciona, agradecería que colocaras lo que hiciste a modo de respuesta, así toda la comunidad sale beneficiada :D

Comment: hola gracias, pero es una gema?

Comment: Supongo, revisé en la red algo referente a tu caso y eso fue lo mejorcito que encontré dada mi limitada visión de ruby (nunca lo he usado), solo sé que Ruby funciona mejor en Mac y distribuciones GNU/Linux

Comment: Podrías probar instalando [ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/releases/download/v1.89/ansi189-bin.zip), al menos sale en ciertas partes que te resolvería el problema y por lo que se ve, está más actualizado que winfowtint o win32console.

Comment: @AlterLagos no me deja correr el servidor.

Comment: @AlterLagos vere lo de la instalacion estimado

Comment: Ok, [aquí hay unas instrucciones](http://softkube.com/blog/ansi-command-line-colors-under-windows) para poder instalarlo y configurarlo correctamente.

Comment: gracias @AlterLagos las seguire

Comment: @AlterLagos no me funciono despues de ansicon.exe -i se supone que me debe salir un output

Comment: @AlterLagos lo malo es que tambien ante la preocupacion que me ha llevado 2 dias esto me cambie a ubuntu 19.10 y este no me reconoce la tarjeta wifi

Comment: No se que más puedas hacer, nunca he programado con ruby para ambientes windows, así que no he tenido esos problemas. Respecto a tu problema en Ubuntu, prueba a conectar tu equipo a través de un cable de red directamente. Es probable que no vengan los controladores para tu tarjeta, pero de seguro puede instalarlos directamente desde internet. Saludos